# Problems with percentage height in google chrome

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, height

why does Google chrome leave images to their original height when it is set in percentage? (if i set it in pixel it shows right)
in IE images on page look right, but in chrome they stretch their width but not their height!
Edit:

```
<div id="Main_NewsBox">
        <span style="display:inline-block;color:White;background-color:Black;height:20%;width:98%;margin:1%;">
          <div style="width:99%;height:98%;margin-top:1%;margin-bottom:1%;margin-  right:1%;;background-color:Color [Black];color:Color [White];margin-bottom:10px;clear:both;position:relative;top:-21px">
            <div style="float:left;width:15%; height:100%"><img style="width:90%;height:95%" alt="" src="Image.png"></div>
            <h1 align="left">Title</h1>
            <div align="right">date</div>
            <div style="word-wrap:break-word" align="left">text</div>
          </div>
        </span>
</div>
```

here the example, this is a "News" that i want on my site, this is the html that chrome displays (in asp.net this is a web control).
why chrome displays the image with its height, whilst, as displayed in IE it should be the div's height?

Comment: post your code here..

Comment: ok, but it ALWAYS happens, not with one particular image or something